# In twitter iOS app segue is not performing visually

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter, xcode5

i am integrating twitter app in my iOS app.the problem is on login when it return to my iOS app the segue which i want to perform is not performing visually, means the transition from one view controller to another is not visible but prepareForSegue method is being called and i can see that in my output console.
    my twitter login method is as follow:
    - (IBAction)tweetbutton:(id)sender {

```
 [SCTwitter initWithConsumerKey:@"your_consumer_key" consumerSecret:@"your_consumer_secret"];    

    [SCTwitter loginViewControler:self callback:^(BOOL success){
        NSLog(@"Login is Success -  %i", success);
        if (success) {

                    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"authentication" sender:self];

        }



    }];




    }

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

       NSLog(@"prepareForSegue: %@", segue.identifier);

}

the output in console is:
2014-12-10 23:54:16.923 gems[1300:60b] Login is Success -  1
2014-12-10 23:54:16.946 gems[1300:60b] prepareForSegue: authentication



i don't understand where i am wrong and  why segue is not performing visually.please suggest a suitable solution and also for your knowledge i am using plain view controller and not navigation controller.

thanks in advance.Any help would be appreciated.
```

Comment: have anyone got any solution of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a segue called "authentication" wired up correctly. You can check that by setting a breakpoint in `prepareForSegue:sender:` method and examine the `segue.destinationViewController` object.

Comment: my segue name is correct and also wired up correctly otherwise console output would never be generated. same segue works well in case of Facebook and google plus login .so please suggest something else. but anyways thank you for the reply.